# Command line script or software tools to label 3d point cloud dataset

Tags: visualization, data-visualization, point-clouds, large-data-volumes, large-data

How can i label a 3d point cloud dataset? is there a software which can load a text file containing x,y,z values and then visualize it , so that I can label it ?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'label a 3d point cloud?'  Do you want to be able to show a label next to all the points in your 3D cloud?  Sounds messy... Do you want to be able to mouse over and see a label for a selected point?

Comment: yep..thats more like it.Like if i have a point cloud from a room with a table and a chair, i want to label them(with a text field) in the dataset as they are clearly visible

Answer (score 1):

A couple 3D graphics packages that come to mind that might help you out.

[VTK](http://www.vtk.org) is an open source 3D Visualization ToolKit.  It's been around a long time -- I used for a grad school research project in 1998.

Matplotlib has a relatively new [3D module](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/), if you like python...

Processing has [3D capabilities](http://processing.org/learning/3d/), if you like java...

Comment: can you give me some real uses of VTK..i saw the docs and its scattered with example in Tcl and has wrappers for C++..I want to use it in C++ mainly.where can i find more examples in c++...the doc that come with VTK is just API docs. The kitware's user guide is not easily available.Is there any tutorial page on how to use VTK for C++

Comment: It's been 10 years since I've used VTK, but I think we did it in C++.  I think the Tcl wraps the C++, not the other way around.  I'm assuming you found C++ examples:

http://vtk.org/VTK/help/examplecode.html

and

http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples#Example_Usage_.28C.2B.2B.29